# How to extract specific data from google form to google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on extracting data from google forms to google sheet and my problem is that I'm still looking how can I get a specific data from the form to google sheet,
I have a google form in which there is some information and I want to know how can I separate the answers in different google sheets

Is there any script to type in google app script editor ?

Thanks.

Comment: You're probably better off writing it as a HTML form rather than a Google form, as far as I know Google forms can only link to 1 specific sheet, then you'd have to move the values afterwards. With HTML you could submit it to a different sheet depending on conditions.

Comment: You could use JSoup or something to try to extract the questions.

Comment: Take a look at the [form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) event object.  All of the data is available for every submission.  And if you have multiple forms feeding multiple linked sheets you can use e.range to determined which linked sheet they are connected to and there which form is making the submission.   Show us your form and tell us what data you want to extract from each submission and we can help you to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

### With Apps Script you have two options

1. You access specific form responses directly and manage them in a desired way (e.g. storing them in a specific Spreadsheet or send them per email), for example triggered by form submission:

---

```
 var form = FormApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
        .forForm(form)
        .onFormSubmit()
        .create();

 function myFunction() {
     var array=[];  
     var formResponses = form.getResponses();
      //i loops through all form submissions, e.g. if 3 users submitted a form - there will be three entries for formResponse
     for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++)
      {
       var formResponse = formResponses[i];
       var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
       // if you are only interested in the answer to question number "j"
       var j=1;
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[j-1];
      array.push(itemResponse.getResponse());
      }
    Logger.log(array);  
 }
```

2. You retrieve the data from the Spreadsheet where your Google Form stores the responses (which you can set up either by selecting the response destination from the form UI or with the Apps Script method [setDestination()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setDestination(DestinationType,String))):

---

```
 var form = FormApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());

 function readSheet() {
     var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
     var responses=sheet.getDataRange();
     //If you are interested in the response to question 3:
     var k=3;
     for(var i=0;i<sheet.getLastRow();i++)
      {
        Logger.log("The response to question "+responses.getValues()[0][k]+" submitted "+ responses.getValues()[i][0]+" is: "+responses.getValues()[i][k])
      }
    }
```